# Linking to other Wiki pages on GitHub?

Tags: github

GitHub wikis allow you to link to other pages in the wiki like so:

```
[[Wiki Page Name]]
```

However, I want to display different text than the wiki page name when making the link. Is there a way to do this? Am I linking to wiki pages all wrong?

Comment: Although markdown is not a programming language, we have plenty of questions tagged XML (another markup language) on StackOverflow. I didn't check but I bet there are some on data exchange formats like JSON. Why not allow this question?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

GitHub by default uses [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) syntax for the wikis so you can just do:

```
[Arbitrary Link Text](Wiki Page Name)
```

Check out [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) and [this blog post](https://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis) for more information about their wikis and the other markup syntaxes they support.

This solution has issues when you're on the home page because it creates relative URLs. Check out [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972756/145530), below.

Comment: Wikis don't use GFM, just normal markdown.

Comment: @Sven's answer is correct, this answer is wrong.

Comment: This creates a relative url link, so if you happen to be in the same directory as the page you're trying to link to it works, otherwise, it does not.  Specifically, if you'er on the Home page (http://.../project_name/wiki), this won't work, because all other pages are in the wiki directory, whereas the homepage isn't.

Comment: -1 since it breaks;  Needs to be updated to include last comment on this thread and I'll change to +1.

Comment: Yes, `[[Link Text|WikiPage]]` works for me. Pleas add to your answer

Comment: -1 since it fails from a saved page but works in preview mode. The preview page is `project/wiki/_preview`, so `[foo|bar]` generates the link `project/wiki/bar` which succeeds. But the saved wiki is just `project/wiki` and the link takes you to `project/bar` which results in a 404. As others have suggested `[[foo|bar]]` links to `project/wiki/bar` in both preview and from the saved page.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Why is it marked as correct and why does it have so many up votes?  @Sven's answer is correct below.

Comment: As of May 2014, this appears to have been fixed on GitHub. This answer now works on all pages. However, the preview is still broken.

Comment: As of August 2019, this doesn't even work in the preview.

Comment: Note that "Wiki Page Name" is not the title but what you see in the url. So "Some Page Name" becomes "Some-Page-Name".

Answer (score 336):

Using the Markdown link syntax

```
[Link Text](WikiPage)
```

seems to work in the edit preview but not on the actual wiki page. At least for me the generated link is `WikiPage` instead of `wiki/WikiPage` and I get the famous [GitHub 404](https://github.com/404).

However the MediaWiki syntax

```
[[Link Text|WikiPage]]
```

works for me, even for Markdown wiki pages.

Comment: This does seem to work consistently, even though it's not in Github's markup documentation.  See my comment on @cbley's answer for why his solution seems to work sometimes but not others.

Comment: Further, if the link text and Wiki page are the same, you can simply use: `[[My Wonderful Wiki Page]]`. This will link to `wiki/My-Wonderful-Wiki-Page`.

Comment: Yes, `[[Link Text|WikiPage]]` works for me. Pleas edit your answer

Comment: @AntonDanilchenko You mean the other way around? First link text then wiki page name separated by a pipe?

Comment: @AntonDanilchenko I just noticed that my answer has been edited on Mar 5. In my initial post I had the link the other way around like you suggested. The "corrected" link may be valid MediaWiki syntax but I wonder if it has been tested with the GitHub wiki flavor?

Comment: Here is a reference to [Add links to wikis](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-links-to-wikis/)

Comment: Note that, as of March, 2019, while MediaWiki syntax works for links with *plain text* as the link text, it breaks when asked to parse link text with any formatting, whether Markdown or MediaWiki syntax.

For example,

```
[[Description of `foo`|Foo]]
```

will render the (code-formatted) source markup, not the intended link. If anyone knows a way around this, please let me know.

Comment: The MediaWiki link works in HTML tags, whereas the Markdown syntax does not.

Comment: To add a link to a heading within another page, use the following syntax: `[[Link Text|WikiPage#heading-in-lowercase-with-spaces-replaced-by-hyphens]]`.  Note that the heading text has to be all lowercase.  Any uppercase letters will break the link.

Answer (score 41):

The *internal-ref* part is relative to your project.  For wiki pages use:

```
[Page Name](wiki/Page-Name)
```

In the preview the link will be broken but when the page is saved it will work.

Comment: Works but Sven's answer works better.

Comment: There is a problem with this when using inside a custom sidebar, if you navigate to one of your link, like `wiki/Page-Name`, then in the `wiki/Page-Name` page's sidebar, links are broken having a double `wiki` element like `wiki/wiki/Page-Name`.

Comment: This does not work within `<html>...</html>` tags whereas `[[Link text|Page Name]]` does.

Comment: When I include "wiki/", the resulting link includes "wiki/wiki/Page-Name".

Answer (score 2):

- The most common use `[Link Text](WikiPageURL)`
- The second way: `[[Link Text|WikiPageURL]]`
- The third way, if you do not want to repeat and need to use the hyperlink several times: `[Link Text]` and at the end of the page use once `[Link Text]:WikiPageURL`

Answer (score -8):

Check the wiki editor's help. It tells you:

> To create a reference link, use two sets of square brackets. `[my internal link][internal-ref]` will link to the internal reference `internal-ref`.

Comment: I also saw that, but it does not work, because - as cbley mentioned - Markdown requires round brackets around internal-ref. I wonder why the help contains wrong information.

Comment: The wiki's help editor does say that, but "internal reference" in this case refers to an in-page Markdown reference, not another page in the same wiki. See the [Markdown link syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax.php#link) for more info.