# Using HTTPS for GitHub Pages in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, https, github-pages

I added a operation to use the microphone for my GitHub Pages hosted blog. But Chrome keeps on asking for media permissions again and again. I found out it [Access Camera & Microphone](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?p=ib_access_cam_mic&rd=1) in Chrome supports. The error message is:

> "If you select Allow on a "http" URL your preference will not be remembered in future visits."

How do I set up or use HTTPS on GitHub Pages? Or at least how can I make Chrome remember to Allow in the preference.

Comment: Off-topic as it is about GitHub Pages hosting (either Web Apps or Webmasters) and not about coding or using Git

Comment: @random Sorry,my native language isn't English.The topic maybe isn't about coding.But I think coding can resolve my question.Because there may be some APIs can help me in Github Pages.And I'm sure it is not a question about Web Apps or Webmasters as [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474045/linking-to-other-wiki-pages-on-github/8972756#8972756).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since June 2016 (three years later), GitHub pages do support https!

See "[HTTPS for GitHub Pages](https://github.com/blog/2186-https-for-github-pages)"

> GitHub Pages now officially1 supports HTTPS for all `<username>.github.io` sites. HTTPS provides a layer of encryption that prevents others from snooping on or tampering with traffic to your Pages site.
>
> You can now visit `*.github.io` sites using HTTPS and configure HTTPS enforcement for your site.
> With HTTPS enforcement enabled, any HTTP requests to your `github.io` site will be transparently redirected to HTTPS.

No need to adjust anything in your Chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Github pages does not support `https` see https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-pages

Comment: Github pages do support https, but I can't find documentation about it. See [link to my page](https://hrj.github.io/) for example.

Comment: Found an excellent article about this (not-official): https://konklone.com/post/github-pages-now-supports-https-so-use-it