# In GitHub Wiki, how do I make a link to another page with a title containing colons?

Tags: github

I know how to make a page link in GitHub's wiki. Normally you can just do:

```
[Arbitrary Link Text](Wiki Page Name)
```

Ref: Stack Overflow question *[Linking to other Wiki pages on GitHub? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474045)*.

But, in my GitHub repository I have a wiki page named "ExampleModule::ExampleClass" with two colons. How do I make a link for it?

I've tried:

```
[Arbitrary Link Text](ExampleModule&#58;&#58;ExampleClass)
```

It doesn't work.

---

Based on the answer, here's my discovering:

Say if I have a page in a GitHub project's wiki repository called `overview`>:

Link to `overview` from wiki repository `Home` page:

```
[Overview](wiki/overview)
```

Link to `overview` from wiki repository that is NOT `Home`:

```
[Overview](../wiki/overview)
```

Link to `overview` from project repository:

```
[Overview](../../wiki/Overview)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a page named `Example::Page`, you could link it with:

```
[Click here](wiki/Example::Page)
```

The colon isn't a problem.

I made a simple example [here](https://github.com/abeaumet/SO_answer/wiki).

Comment: Colons in the page name work fine for linking, but they can be problematic if you ever check out your Wiki repo. I've tried with both MSysGit 1.8.3 and SourceTree 1.4.1.0, and neither one can check out the `Example::Page.md` file. MSysGit gives ```error: unable to create file Example::Page.md (Invalid argument)
fatal: unable to checkout working tree``` and leaves the file in deleted state. SourceTree creates an untracked file `Example\357\200\272\357\200\272Page.md` and leaves the original file name deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It seems the problem you encounter is Windows specific (at least I don't have it under the Mac OS X git client and I think it wouldn't occur neither on the Linux client). Try to open a ticket on the concerned bug platforms.

Answer (score 0):

For relative links you can use `./fancy-page:-name`, eg:

```
## Protocols
- [Log](./Message-Protocol:-Log)
- [Warning](./Message-Protocol:-Warning)
```

I noticed that if you tried to do something like `[Log](Message-Protocol:-Log)`, the link would not work. I tried adding `./` before the link so that it becomes `[Log](./Message-Protocol:-Log)` and that works for me.